# Find brackets and adding content around them in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a few documents that have brackets at the start of each line that go like

`[8-1 1:2] apples
[8-2 1:3] oranges
[10-5 4:1] bananas`

So the numbers aren't sequential, if that matters. What I want to do is to add some html code around them like

`<html>[8-1 1:2] </html> apples
<html>[8-2 1:3] </html> oranges
<html>[10-5 4:1] </html> bananas`

So far i've managed to use regex to find the brackets and info around them, but I can't make it just add the content around while keeping the brackets and what's inside intact.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use capture groups in your regexp (delimited by parens). And then do the replace mixing what you captured and what you want to add.

This could be done like this:

```
(\[\d+-\d+\s+\d+:\d+\])\s*([a-zA-Z]+)
```

The first capture group would be the numbers between the brackets. The second group would be the text.

So, in the replace text box, you'd add something like:

```
<html>$1</html> $2
```

Where `$1` and `$2` are the capture groups.

Comment: My version of notepad++ uses `\1` `\2` ... instead of `$1`, `$2`.

Comment: do not specify \d+-\d+\s+\d+:\d+\, make simply .*

Comment: @ktaria. Well, that really depends on what you are trying to match and what your real data looks like. If it's ok to match *anything* enclosed by brackets, fine. If you're looking for a more specific pattern as it seems to be the case, `.*` might not be a good fit.

Comment: @agbinfo: You have a very old version. It's time to upgrade.

Comment: @ktaria Rather than reducing to `.*` (or even `.+`) it may be better to search for `[^\[\]]*`, then the whole search expression becomes `(\[[^\[\]]*\])\s*([a-zA-Z]+)`. For this question there seems little to choose between `*` and `+` within the first capture.

Comment: @M42. I switched to Sublime a long time ago and I barely use notepad, that's why I didn't bother upgrading it.